# Motherboard s2600cp and CPU slots

Tags: cpu, motherboard

Hi I am trying to assembly s2600cp intel motherboard with Intel Xeon E5 processor. It only seems to work when processor is placed onto CPU1 slot. Does CPU1 and CPU2 choice for processor placement really matter ?

Comment: Have you checked the manual for supported CPU configurations? It makes sense that CPU1 must be installed honestly.

Comment: sounds reasonable, still I can not find it in manual

Comment: Yes, it matters. Part of the PCI-e lanes these days come from the circuitry on the CPU-die. If you do not connect those (by placing the CPU in socket #0/1 rather than 1/2) you miss out on functionality. Which likely includes functions needed to boot.

Answer (score 1):

Intel's own [S2600CP Technical Product Specification](http://www.manualowl.com/m/Intel/S2600CP/Manual/299886?page=43) states on Page 43, Section 4.1.2

> "When using a single processor configuration, the processor must be
>   installed into the processor socket labeled CPU1."

(FYI NOTE: This section also describes the rules for dual-processor configurations)